# How to check if a Button is pressed so another can be disabled | Flutter

Tags: for-loop, button, flutter, dart

I have a for Loop where articles get loaded into a Widget and I only want one to be enabled, so how can I do that?

So far I got it working, but it doesn't recognise if I pressed another Button and I am relatively new to Flutter so I don't exactly know how I can implement such a feature.

**Widget for Articles**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:wiegon/icons/nuleo_icons.dart';
import 'package:wiegon/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:wiegon/pages/control_screen.dart';
import 'package:wiegon/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

class ArticleandAmount extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: new SvgPicture.asset(wiegonLogo,
                    allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
                    semanticsLabel: 'Wiegon Logo'),
                onPressed: null,
              );
            },
          ),
          title: Text(
            "Artikel und Menge",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xffFDFEFE)),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff466988),
        ),
        body: Articleamount(),
        endDrawer: Enddrawer());
  }
}

class Articleamount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ArticleamountState createState() {
    return _ArticleamountState();
  }
}

String displayedWeight;
String displayedTotalPrice;
String displayedPrice;
String articleID;
String unit = "";

String articleSelected = "Artikel wählen";

class _ArticleamountState extends State<Articleamount> {
  final amountController = TextEditingController();

  static Color disabledColor = mainColor.withOpacity(0.5);

  double price = 0.0;
  double inputAmount = 0;
  bool isArticleSelected = false;
  bool isPriceSelected = false;
  Color buttonColor = disabledColor;

  String totalPrice = "0";

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the paremeters when the widget is disposed.
    unit = "";
    articlesList = {};
    articleSelected = "Artikel wählen";
    amountController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget articleCard(
      String articleName, IconData icon, double priceForArticle) {
    String tempunit = articleName.split("|")[1];
    String tempID = articleName.split("&")[1].split("|")[0];
    articleName = articleName.split("&")[0];
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      width: 300,
      height: 120,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: MaterialButton(
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              articleName,
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
        highlightColor: Colors.blue,
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          10,
        )),
        elevation: 2,
        onPressed: () {
          articleSelected = articleName;
          articleID = tempID;
          setState(() {
            amountController.text = "";
            totalPrice = "0";
            buttonColor = disabledColor;
            inputAmount = 0;
            unit = tempunit;
            price = priceForArticle;
            isArticleSelected = true;
          });
        },
      ),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
      FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: deviceWidth(context),
          child: Center(
              child: Container(
                  width: 600,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            progressBar(Nucleo.checked, "Bürger", true),
                            progressLine(true, context),
                            progressBar(
                                Nucleo.selected_two, "Artikel und Menge", true),
                            progressLine(false, context),
                            progressBar(Nucleo.three, "Buchung", false),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Bürger".toUpperCase(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              new Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                getCitizenInformation(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17, color: secondaryColor),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                              // width: 600,
                              child: Row(children: [
                                Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Artikel und Menge wählen",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: secondaryColor,
                                          fontSize: 21,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                                        height: 5,
                                        width: 30,
                                        color: secondaryColor)
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ]),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  color: Colors.transparent),
                              width: 600,
                              child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Wrap(
                                      alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        for (var article in articlesList.keys)
                                          articleCard(
                                              article,
                                              MdiIcons.chessQueen,
                                              articlesList[article])
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                                          height: 70,
                                          width: 600,
                                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                width: 220,
                                                margin:
                                                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                                child: TextField(
                                                  onChanged: (text) {
                                                    totalPrice = calculatePrice(
                                                        text, price);
                                                  },
                                                  keyboardType:
                                                      TextInputType.number,
                                                  controller: amountController,
                                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 13),
                                                      labelText:
                                                          "$articleSelected"),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "á € $price / $unit",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: primaryColor,
                                                    fontSize: 20),
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                "$totalPrice€",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: secondaryColor,
                                                    fontSize: 20,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                                      child: Row(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          ButtonTheme(
                                            minWidth: 280,
                                            height: 50,
                                            child: OutlineButton(
                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                  color: mainColor, width: 2),
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          10)),
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Zurück",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: mainColor,
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          MaterialButton(
                                              minWidth: 280,
                                              height: 50,
                                              color: buttonColor,
                                              elevation: 0,
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          10)),
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Weiter",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                if (isArticleSelected == true &&
                                                    isPriceSelected == true &&
                                                    inputAmount != 0) {
                                                  Navigator.push(
                                                      context,
                                                      PageTransition(
                                                          type: PageTransitionType
                                                              .rightToLeftWithFade,
                                                          child:
                                                              Controlscreen()));
                                                } else {
                                                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                                      msg:
                                                          "Eingaben bitte überprüfen",
                                                      toastLength:
                                                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                                      gravity:
                                                          ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                                                      timeInSecForIos: 1,
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                          Colors.red,
                                                      textColor: Colors.white,
                                                      fontSize: 16.0);
                                                }
                                              }),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ]))))
    ]));
  }

  String calculatePrice(String inputText, double price) {
    double amount;
    if (inputText.isNotEmpty) {
      amount = double.parse(inputText);
    } else {
      amount = 0;
    }
    double total = (amount * price);

    setState(() {
      totalPrice = total.toStringAsFixed(2);
      isPriceSelected = true;
      inputAmount = amount;
      buttonColor = mainColor;
    });

    displayedTotalPrice = totalPrice;
    displayedWeight = amount.toString();
    displayedPrice = price.toString();

    return totalPrice;
  }
}
```

Comment: Only with the code shown is complicated to analyze.

From the above, I'd say your `articleSelected` variable is in the wrong place, it should be in the widget where the loop happens, not in the article widget.

It would be nice to show this complete part of the code. Can you show it?

Comment: I added the whole code :)

Comment: I know this goes against what a commenter above asked, but it's difficult to identify your problem about two button that you want to have a dependency on each other from 379 lines of code. Could you try to isolate your problem into a small example?

Comment: do you want only one button to be enabled? on which condition you are thinking it to achieve? plz explain basic functionality with some use case example and if UI is shown that will also be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable to know if a button is already pressed. Like this:

```
var isSelected = false;
FlatButton(
      onPressed: () => { isSelected = true },
      child: Text(
        "Selling"
      ),
      color: isSelected ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor : Colors.grey,
),
```